# ¿Como ponerle valores numericos a una matriz que se expande es decir 2x2, 4x4 y asi?

Tags: python

Hola estoy tratando de poner valores numéricos en una tabla-matriz donde al poner que sea 4x4, 6x6 o 8x8 el usuario ponga las reinas correspondientes en posiciones que uno quiere(de acuerdo a la expansion o crecimiento si quiere que sea 4x4 solo pueda poner 4 con 6x6 ponga 6) que se vean con el símbolo 'X' en las casillas que quiera y el resto de las casillas se consideren 0 y que no sea usando la función random de manera al azar que sea como el usuario lo ponga
No se si pueda como esta escrito en la función o tiene que ser uno por uno.
Este es el codigo que estoy usando:

```
import random
# <============================== functions ==============================> #
# it will create a initial state of queens for us :
Reyna= int(input("Cuantas Reinas desea Usar(Solo se aceptan Numeros Pares no Impares) "))
def randomRestart():
columnList = [0] * Reyna
for col in range(Reyna):
    columnList[col] = random.randint(1, Reyna)
return columnList

def printBoard(columnList):
for row in range(Reyna, 0, -1):
    for col in range(Reyna):
        if columnList[col] == row:
            print("X", end="  ")
        else:
            print(0, end="  ")
    print()

queensPositions = randomRestart()
print("Posicion de Columnas de Las Reinas : ", queensPositions)
print("Posicion Inicial de las Reinas: ")
print('\n***********************\n')
printBoard(queensPositions)
print('\n***********************\n')
print("==========================================================================")
```

Esta es el resultado que da con la funcion random:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No veo la relación entre la pregunta y el código.

Comment: ya corregi tanto la pregunta como respuesta es como este cofigo solo que se cambien los valores por X y 0 n = 6
a = [[0] * n for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i < j:
            a[i][j] = 0
        elif i > j:
            a[i][j] = 2
        else:
            a[i][j] = 1
for row in a:
    print(' '.join([str(elem) for elem in row]))

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de cuál es el resultado que deseas?

Comment: O sea que la pregunta es ¿como hacerlo sin usar `random`?

Comment: ¿Estás queriendo hacer el juego de las n reinas?

Comment: Si estoy haciendo el juego de las n reinas, pero sin usar la funcion random

Comment: No estoy entendiendo muy bien. Si quieres colocar las reinas en posiciones aleatorias pero sin usar random pues se te va hacer defícil, pero como mencionas el  juego de las n reinas entonces lo que tienes que hacer es un algoritmo que verifique las posiciones de las reinas y hacia donde se mueve y en el lugar donde no haya amenaza colocar a la reina

Comment: Bueno si lo quiero poner las reinas en posiciones que un usuario quiera que se ven con el simbolo 'X' y el resto que no ha asigando una reina se considere un 0

Comment: No entiendo nada.. si el usuario te dice las posiciones, cual es el problema? mas que recorrer el array, tenes que ir a la posicion que te pidio el usuario y ponerlo ahi...

Comment: Ahora si que no acabo de entender nada, es mejor que edites la pregunta para aclararla y que pongas un ejemplo de lo que quieres y la salida que esperas.

Comment: Bueno ya lo corregui, de acuerdo como lo quiera el usuario como cuadro 4x4, 6x6, 8x8 y asi solo pueda poner reinas igual a la cantidad que le perimita 4, 6, 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien lo que quieres entonces un ciclo `for` debería bastar para rellenar el tablero.

```py
print("se genrará un tablero de nxn de acuerdo al número de reynas que ingrese")
num_reynas = int(input("Ingrese el número de reinas"))

#generamos una matriz n por n usando una list comprehesion
tablero = [[0]*num_reynas for _ in range(num_reynas)]
```

En el código anterior solo pedimos al usuario que ingrese el numero de reynas y generamos una matri que representará de forma correcta el tablero, para ello usamos una list comprehesion que es una forma abreviada de escribir un ciclo `for`.

El siguiente paso es usar un ciclo `for` para pedir al usuario que ingrese las posiciones en las que quiere que las reynas vaya en el tablero.

```py
print("Coloque las reinas en las posiciones")
for _ in range(num_reynas):
    fila = int(input("Ingrese la fila"))
    columna = int(input("Ingrese la columna"))

    tablero[fila][columna] = "X"
```

Con el código anterior pedimos que ingrese la fila y columna donde quiere que vaya la reina, en esa psición colocamos la `X`, esto se repetirá según el número de reynas que haya ingresado el usuario. A ese ciclo aún le falta validar si la posición es correcta pero eso ya lo dejo para ti.

Como mencionaste en los comentarios que querías guardar el número de la columna donde se ubican las reinas entonces lo único que debemos hacer es guardar la variable `columna` que hay en el ciclo for en otra lista, sería algo así:

```py
columnas_reynas = []

print("Coloque las reinas en las posiciones")
for _ in range(num_reynas):
    fila = int(input("Ingrese la fila"))
    columna = int(input("Ingrese la columna"))

    tablero[fila][columna] = "X"
    columnas_reynas.append(columna)
```

Una observación, si se colocan 2 reynas en una misma columna entonces la lista `columnas_reynas` tendrá datos duplicados, si usarás la lista después y no necesitas duplicados entonces puedes hacer `columnas_reynas = list(set(columnas_reynas))`, lo que hace `set` es eliminar duplicados. O si te parece mejor puedes guardar la posicion `x` y `y` de la reina, haciendo `columnas_reynas.append((fila, columna))` y así tendras una lista de tuplas.Si tienes alguna duda me la dejas en los comentarios :D.

Comment: Hola buenas, si me sirvió el código que pusiste, ahora puedo poner las reinas en cualquier parte del tablero que quiera pregunta: ¿hay forma de que me aparezca la posición de columnas de la reina como en el ejemplo que puse? como se pone con la funcion random excepto que sea manualmente

Comment: @MartinFlores edite la respuesta, espero resolver tu duda

Comment: Si me resolvio la parte de la posicion de las filas, ahora que los pongo me aparece en 0 estuve intentando si se puede cambiar a 1 es decir en las coordenadas del primer programa me aparecian del 1 al 4 y esta modificacion me aparece el 0 al 3 ademas de que la impresion de las reinas no me pone en las coordenadas correctas se me mueven o aparece en 0 todo

Comment: Recuerda que las posiciones en una lista van del `0` a `n-1`. Si tienes problemas recomiendo que hagas otra pregunta y que añadas todos los detalles posibles junto con el nuevo código.

Comment: Set en realidad crea un objeto de Python especial. Si no te importa el orden, todos los elementos de la lista son hashables (como numeros) y no deben repetirse, entonces es mejor trabajar con un set directamente que con una lista. Tambien hay que tener en cuenta que la linea de código list(set(...)), En el mejor de los casos, no conserva el orden original de los elementos del iterable.