# ¿Como puedo poner las coordenadas de la columna en una matriz?

Tags: python

Hola estoy tratando de poner las coordenadas de una o mas piezas de ajedrez reina en un programa que me permite un poner un tabla-matriz donde al poner que sea 4x4, 6x6 o 8x8 el usuario ponga las reinas correspondientes en posiciones que uno quiere(de acuerdo a la expansion o crecimiento si quiere que sea 4x4 solo pueda poner 4 con 6x6 ponga 6) que se vean con el símbolo 'R'. Al momento de ejecutar el codigo me pone las posiciones de la reina como 0 u 'R' en la parte de posicion de columnas de la reina y no se como cambiar en esa parte que me de coordenadas de las columnas de la reina y no cambie le resulatdo de las piezas a la hora insertarlas.
Este es el codigo que estoy usando:

```
# <============================== functions ==============================> #
print("Cuantas Reinas desea Usar(Solo se aceptan Numeros Pares no Impares) \n")
num_reynas = int(input("Ingrese el número de reinas "))
columnas_reynas=[]
#############################################################################
def randomRestart():
 #generamos una matriz n por n usando una list comprehesion
 tablero = [[0]*num_reynas for _ in range(num_reynas)]

 print("Coloque las reinas en las posiciones\n")
 for _ in range(num_reynas):
   fila = int(input("Ingrese la fila--> "))
   columna = int(input("Ingrese la columna--> "))

   tablero[fila][columna] = "R"
   columnas_reynas.append(columna)
   #columnas_reynas.append((fila, columna))
 #return columnas_reynas
   return tablero
#############################################################################
def printBoard(columnList):
    fila = len(columnList)
    columna = len(columnList[0])
    for i in range(fila):
           for j in range(columna):
              print(" {0} ".format(columnList[i][j]), sep=',', end='')
           print('')
          #columnas_reynas.append(columna)
   queensPositions = randomRestart()
   print("\nPosicion de Columnas de Las Reinas : ", queensPositions)
   print("Posicion Inicial de las Reinas: ")
   print('\n***********************\n')
   printBoard(queensPositions)
   print('\n***********************\n')
   print("==========================================================================")
```

Y esto es como quiero que aparezca el programa:

```
Posicion de Columnas de Las Reinas : [3,4,2,1]
  Posicion Inicial de las Reinas:
  ***********************

   0  R  0  0
   R  0  0  0
   0  0  R  0
   0  0  0  R
 
  ***********************
```

Con esto ejecuto el programa que me sale las coordenadas pero alparecer me cambia el cuadro de las reinas:

```
     tablero[fila][columna] = "R"
  columnas_reynas.append(columna)
  #columnas_reynas.append((fila, columna))
return columnas_reynas

def printBoard(columnas_reynas):
  for fila in range(num_reynas, 0, -1):
     for columna in range(num_reynas):
         if columnas_reynas[columna] == fila:
             print("R", end="  ")
         else:
             print(0, end="  ")
     #columnas_reynas = list(set(columnas_reynas))
    print()

    printBoard(queensPositions)
```

Esto es una muestra de como se ejecuto el programa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál, es tu problema con el código? Por favor evita crear la misma pregunta otra vez, solo agrega la info que haga falta y avisa que la has agregado.

Comment: Ya especifique como mas en la informacion que falto poner

Comment: `Posicion de Columnas de Las Reinas : [3,4,2,1]` ¿Que se supone significa esto?

Comment: Son las posiciones de las columnas de reinas ese lo hace casi el mismo código del problema solo que antes utilice la función fandom para sacar los números al azar y ahora necesito se requiere que el usuario digite las coordenadas de las piezas manualmente. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/562826/como-ponerle-valores-numericos-a-una-matriz-que-se-expande-es-decir-2x2-4x4-y

Comment: Se te muestra una matriz al momento de imprimir por que estas imprimiendo la variable incorrecta, deberías imprimir `columnas_reynas` que contiene las columnas en donde se encuentran las reinas.

Comment: Si en el ejemplo del codigo lo ejecuto con el columnas_reynas me sale las coordenadas bien pero la impresion del tablero por lo que vi solo me toma el coordenadas de la columna y no me toma ambos donde tendria que estar R